# How to write to a file name defined at runtime?

Tags: apache-beam

I want to write to a gs file but I don’t know the file name at compile time. Its name is based on behavior that is defined at runtime. How can I proceed?

Comment: OK, do you know the folder, where files could be stored?

Comment: Are you using Beam Java or Python?

Comment: Java. Using standard TextIO

Comment: Let’s say the folder is gs://bucket/myfolder/

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Beam Java, you can use `FileIO.writeDynamic()` for this (starting with Beam 2.3 which is currently in the process of being released - but you can already use it via the version `2.3.0-SNAPSHOT`), or the older `DynamicDestinations` API (available in Beam 2.2).

Example of using `FileIO.writeDynamic()` to write a `PCollection` of bank transactions to different paths on GCS depending on the transaction's type:

```
PCollection<BankTransaction> transactions = ...;
transactions.apply(
    FileIO.<BankTransaction, TransactionType>writeDynamic()
      .by(Transaction::getType)
      .via(BankTransaction::toString, TextIO.sink())
      .to("gs://bucket/myfolder/")
      .withNaming(type -> defaultNaming("transactions_", ".txt"));
```

For an example of `DynamicDestinations` use, see [example code in the TextIO unit tests](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/eddfa0d92779f636458954a9292fc0bfa965a123/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIOWriteTest.java#L98).

Alternatively, if you want to write each record to its own file, just use the `FileSystems` API (in particular, `FileSystems.create()`) from a `DoFn`.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: @jkff is there a performance between using FileSystems.create vs. writeDynamic?

Comment: I haven't benchmarked them, but there's not much else going on in writeDynamic performance-wise except for what you'd already be doing with FileSystems.create. It does use FileSystems.create under the hood.

Comment: How does this work with Beam 2.6? The signatures and / or  the functions seem to have changed

Comment: If you are referring to the `.via(___, ___)` line, then it looks like it needs to wrap the 1st argument in a `Contextful.fn(___)`

Answer (score 2):

For the Python crowd:

An experimental write was added to the Beam python SDK in 2.14.0, `beam.io.fileio.WriteToFiles`:

```
my_pcollection | beam.io.fileio.WriteToFiles(
      path='/my/file/path',
      destination=lambda record: 'avro' if record['type'] == 'A' else 'csv',
      sink=lambda dest: AvroSink() if dest == 'avro' else CsvSink(),
      file_naming=beam.io.fileio.destination_prefix_naming())
```

which can be used to write to different files per-record.

If your filename is based on data within your pcollections, you can use the `destination` and `file_naming` to create files based on each record's data.

More documentation here:

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#dynamic-destinations

And the JIRA issue here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2857

Answer (score 2):

As @anrope mentioned already, [apache_beam.io.fileio](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.15.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html) seems to be the latest Python API for writing files. The WordCount example is currently outdated since it uses the WriteToText class, which inherits from the now deprecated [apache_beam.io.filebasedsink](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.filebasedsink.html) / [apache_beam.io.iobase](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.iobase.html)

To add to existing answers, here is my pipeline in which I dynamically name the output files during runtime. My pipeline takes N input files and creates N output files, which are named based on their corresponding input file name.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    (p
        | 'CreateFiles' >> beam.Create(input_file_paths)
        | 'MatchFiles' >> MatchAll()
        | 'OpenFiles' >> ReadMatches()
        | 'LoadData' >> beam.Map(custom_data_loader)
        | 'Transform' >> beam.Map(custom_data_transform)
        | 'Write' >> custom_writer
    )
```

When I load the data I create a PCollection of tuple records `(file_name, data)`. All my transforms are applied to `data`, but I pass `file_name` through to the end of the pipeline to generate the output file names.

```
def custom_data_loader(f: beam.io.fileio.ReadableFile):
    file_name = f.metadata.path.split('/')[-1]
    data = custom_read_function(f.open())
    return file_name, data

def custom_data_transform(record):
    file_name, data = record
    data = custom_transform_function(data)  # not defined
    return file_name, data
```

And I save the file with:

```
def file_naming(record):
    file_name, data = record
    file_name = custom_naming_function(file_name)  # not defined
    return file_name

def return_destination(*args):
    """Optional: Return only the last arg (destination) to avoid sharding name format"""
    return args[-1]

custom_writer = WriteToFiles(
    path='path/to/output',
    file_naming=return_destination,
    destination=file_naming,
    sink=TextSink()
)
```

Replace all of the `custom_*` functions with your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of an old question but I struggled with the examples in the documentation.

Here is a simple example of how to split files based on dict items.

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = False


def file_names(*args):
    file_name = fileio.destination_prefix_naming()(*args)
    destination, *_ = file_name.split("----")
    return f"{destination}.json"


class JsonSink(fileio.TextSink):
    def write(self, element):
        record = json.loads(element)
        record.pop("id")
        self._fh.write(json.dumps(record).encode("utf8"))
        self._fh.write("\n".encode("utf8"))


def destination(element):
    return json.loads(element)["id"]


with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    data = [
        {"id": 0, "message": "whhhhhhyyyyyyy"},
        {"id": 1, "message": "world"},
        {"id": 1, "message": "hi there!"},
        {"id": 1, "message": "what's up!!!?!?!!?"},
    ]

    (
        p
        | "CreateEmails" >> beam.Create(data)
        | "JSONify" >> beam.Map(json.dumps)
        | "Write Files"
        >> fileio.WriteToFiles(
            path="path/",
            destination=destination,
            sink=lambda dest: JsonSink(),
            file_naming=file_names,
        )
    )
```